# Equivalent to R runmin and runmax functions in Python?

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to translate some R scripts to Python but I can't find equivalent to `runmin` and `runmax` from `caTools` ([Link to `caTools` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/caTools.pdf)).

This is the R code:

```
shift <- 250
...
min <- runmin(Array, k = shift, align = "right")
max <- runmax(Array, k = shift, align = "right")
```

Comment: And what does `runmin `and `runmax` do in [R]?

Comment: Many of the Python developers won't be familiar with `runmax` and `runmin`  [R]. Please explain with example regarding what it does

Comment: What I understand when I execute the script, it returns a sorted column,  not everything is sorted. It looks like that shift parameter is doing something, like setting an interval.

Comment: C'mon man, down voting... really?

Comment: I didn't jump on the downvote train, but looking up the documentation for `runmin` and `runmax` and being able to explain it at least *tiny* bit seems like basic due diligence. Your comment *"it returns a sorted column, not everything is sorted. It looks like that shift parameter is doing something, like setting an interval"* makes it seem like you didn't put much effort in before asking the question.

Comment: @Gregor «you didn't put much effort»? I never did R and Python before. I understand it's not clear for a Python developper, but I'm sure someone who did R before understand.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the [`runmin` and `runmax` from `caTools`](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/caTools/html/runminmax.html).

In Python you can use the [`minfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter.html#scipy-ndimage-filters-minimum-filter) and [`maxfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html#scipy-ndimage-filters-maximum-filter) from scipy. The `k` parameter in `runmin` is equivalent to the `size` parameter of the moving window.

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import minimum_filter, maximum_filter
>>> minimum_filter([5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], size=3)
array([5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 9])

>>> maximum_filter([5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], size=3)
array([ 6,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 10])
```

However it does not support `align`. It should be possible to use `origin` instead:

```
>>> maximum_filter([5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], size=3, origin=1)
array([ 6,  6,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> maximum_filter([5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], size=3, origin=-1)
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10])
```

I'd say that right align is equals to `origin=(size//2)` (or the negative) but you probably need to verify this yourself.

Comment: Yeah from caTools. Very interesting! I will dig min and maxfilter thanks.